# Hibernate получить список по условию, иначе вернуть все сущности в списке

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jpa

Пусть есть сущность User:(для простоты имеет 2 поля)

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

Есть слой репозитория:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    Optional<User> findUserByName(String userName);

    List<User> findUserByNameContaining(String fragment);
```

Имеется контроллер, с двумя эндпоинтами:

```
   @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<User>getAllUsers(){
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/all{nameFragment}")
    public List<User>getAllUsers( @PathVariable(name = "nameFragment") String nameFragment){
        return userService.findUserByNameContaining(nameFragment);
    }
```

Могу ли я как нибудь объединить два этих эндпоинта в один в метод

```
 @GetMapping("/all{nameFragment}")
    public List<User>getAllUsers( @PathVariable(name = "nameFragment") String nameFragment){
        return userService.findUserByNameContaining(nameFragment);
    }
```

И в зависимости от того, передал ли я аргумент `nameFragment` или нет, будет выполнять поиск либо пользователя, содержащего в себе часть `nameFragment` или в случае, если `nameFragment=null`будет выводиться все пользователи

т.е можно ли создать примерно такой метод в репозитории:

```
findUserByNameContainingElseFindAll(String nameFragment)
```

Или данную логику поведения нужно отдельно обрабатывать в сервисном слое ?

Answer (score 1):

Для "объединения" эндпойнтов в контроллере достаточно указать, что параметр запроса является необязательным `required = false` (также следует добавить `/` для разграничения параметра):

```java
// контроллер
@GetMapping("/all/{nameFragment}")
public List<User>getAllUsers(
    @PathVariable(name = "nameFragment", required = false) String nameFragment
) {
    userService.findUserByNameContaining(nameFragment);
}
```

На уровне сервиса можно либо вызвать соответствующий метод существующего репозитория после проверки параметра на `null`:

```java
// сервис
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

public List<User> findUserByNameContaining(String nameFragment) {
    return null == nameFragment
        ? userRepo.findAll()
        : userRepo.findUserByNameContaining(nameFragment);
}
```

---

Можно также написать кастомный запрос в репозитории и вызвать этот метод из сервиса напрямую, для использования `LIKE` придётся использовать [JPQL-функцию `CONCAT`](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/jpa_overview_query.html#jpa_overview_query_functions):

```java
// репо
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR u.name LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(?1, '%')))")
    List<User> findUserByNameContaining(String fragment);
}
```